# Does an id_token need to be stored, or can it just be used once to create a session?

Tags: security, authentication, oauth-2.0, openid-connect

I'm trying to implement [Twitch login via the OIDC authorization flow](https://dev.twitch.tv/docs/authentication/getting-tokens-oidc), and am confused around how to correctly (and safely) use the `id_token` I get back. I know you should verify the authenticity of the token with Twitch before using it, but after that do I need to store the token somewhere for access on every request, or can I just use it once to initialize a session?

Pseudo-code for the logic where I don't store the id_token

```
id_token, access_token, refresh_token = twitchOIDCLogin()
verifyIdToken(id_token)
userId = extractUserId(id_token)
session.set({ 
  userId: userId, 
  access_token: access_token, 
  refresh_token: refresh_token })
```

And then on subsequent requests, the user being "logged in" is solely determined by the sessionID cookie linking to a session in my session store.

Is this secure/correct, or should I be storing the id_token and verifying it on every request? And if so, should I then be forcing the user through the authentication flow again once the id_token expires?

Answer (score 0):

The ID token often have a very short lifetime, like 5 minutes and after you have  created your local session, you can just delete it as it has no further purpose.

Comment: Hi @Tore Nestenius, can you elaborate more? what do you mean by local session? like stored in a variable in a authservice object?

Comment: what I mean is, after a successful openid-connect authentication, you get your tokens, but then what do you want to happen next? Typically, you create a local "user session", setting a cookie and to identify the user on all requests between the browser and the backend. The Id-token is typically used for creating this "sesssion". The ID-token after this has no/little use except it might be needed when you later signout. The ID-token is after you received it not sent any where, except it might be needed for signout.